# Regular expression to capture html tag style syntax using double brackets

Tags: php, regex, parsing, syntax, logic

I'm writing up Yet Another Template Engine in PHP. Should Mustache.php really be 1.6mb?? I want something lighter and completely workflow Agnostic. What happened to the good ole days of including a vendor file and using it?

Anyhow, the syntax is simple and such I have a very simple working preg_replace working for simple variables i.e. [[variable]]

However I'm running into an issue whereas I'd like to to catch encapsulated conditional content. I.e

`[[#if this == 'that']]
To be seen or not to be that is the question!
[[/if]]`

Below is my current regex and its very close, however I can't seem to work out the proper rules for the closing `[[/if]]` tag;

**It captures past the closing tag :(**

`preg_match('/\\[\\[#if(.+)\\]\\][^\\[\\]\\/](.+)\\[\\[\\/if\\]\\]/s', $template, $ifmatches);`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is my modification to your regex:](http://regex101.com/r/yW5lP7)

```
\[\[#(\w+)\s(.*?)\]\](.*?)\[\[\/\1\]\]
```

Changes that I made:

- I removed the literal text for "if" and instead matched it with a short-hand character class `\w` between 1 and unlimited times. I placed this into a capture group with the backreference number of 1.
- As per your regex, I matched a space after the tag name... and then matched any character, between 0 and unlimited times, **as few times as possible** `(.*?)` with backreference number 2.
- The characters between the tags are also matched **as few times as possible** with the `?` quantifier and placed into backreference 3.
- In the closing tag, I used a backreference to capture group 1, so that the tags are always consistent.

The thing that really makes this work better is the `?` quantifier. It turns the expression "lazy" which is a good thing, because it doesn't "over-reach".

**Here's a demo to show how it works:**

> [**'?' Quantifier demonstration**](http://regex101.com/r/lQ8xB5)

Comment: Hi Vasili, not sure who voted your answer down, but I'd vote it up if I could (not enough reputation yet). Your regex works perfectly and is  definitely more elegantly written! My regex was choking up see [here](http://regex101.com/r/hD8jJ5). I'm still not exactly sure where I went wrong? But thank you very much for helping :) P.s Thanks for introducing me to regex101.com.. Amazing utility.

Comment: No problems. Since it worked, I'll write up a bit more about how my regex works. Just upvote and accept the answer whenever you can, no biggie. Most people downvote answers on anything that has to do with HTML or XML, because some zealots think regex should never be used with it.

Comment: By the way, does the expression need to have all the \ characters escaped twice, as per your question?

Comment: Funny about the double backslash. I never used it before but saw it being used in couple of php regular expressions including the one used by WordPress for their shortcodes and desperate for a solution I threw them in there.. Kinda weird, I prefer them out! Thanks again for the help and I'll certainly upvote once I'm able to